# Area of intersection of n circles each having radius 'r'

Tags: math, intersection, area

Prob Statement:
'N' equal radii circles are plotted on a graph from (-)infinity to (+)infinity.Find the total area of intersection I.e all the area on the graph which is covered by two or more circles.

Comment: The programming part of this question is? Sounds like simply Mathematics to me. What language are you doing this in?

Comment: if the above link doesnot work then pls refer to this:

http://i.imagehost.org/0772/circles.png

Comment: Yes it's more of mathematics. I am doing it in C

Comment: Note for the image:
 i)the area in green needs to be calculated.
ii)all the curves in image are circles not ovals

Comment: cont of Note: all the circles have same radius 'r'

Comment: *"all the circles have same radius 'r'"* You keep saying that but---even allowing for differential scaling---that is not what the image shows. Not to worry, the problem is still approachable. The way you asked the question could be taken to apply that all the centers lie on the x-axis, but that is not what the image shows. Which is it? Also, is there a limit to the number of circles to consider?

Comment: @Dan McG et al: Given as how there is no closed form solution, the answer will have to *be coded*. That is why this *is* programming related.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly a correction: these aren't circles. They're ellipses (circles being a special case of ellipses where a = b). You can calculate the intersection of two ellipses so given N ellipses you need to check each pair, so the entire operation is O(n<sup>2</sup>) (multiplied by whatever the intersection operation is).

Take a look at [Intersection of Ellipses](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/IntersectionOfEllipses.pdf) and [The Area of Intersecting Ellipses](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/AreaIntersectingEllipses.pdf).

**Edit:** the intersection of circles is an easier problem but follows the same principle. Take a look at [Intersection Of Two Circles](http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/2circle/) and [Circle-Circle Intersection](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html).

Comment: sorry, my image isn't that perfect... 
all the curves in he image represent equi radii circles.

Comment: This is hard because you have to deal with cases where more than 2 overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest (not necessarily fastest or "best") way to code is to find the bounding box that contains all circles and then use a numerical stochastic method to integrate.

Now by being smart you can probably group circles and box them separately, i.e work in a number of bounding boxes. And even handle certain special cases exactly.

But a pure stochastic method has the beauty of being easy to implement (but potentially slow).

This is only acceptable if you are happy to have an "approximate" (but arbitrarily close to correct) answer.

Comment: Good if rough or modest precision is acceptable. *Definitely* want to detect overlapping groups and draw bounding boxes around each group though: there is the potential for insane quantities of whitespace otherwise.